# ansible find and change permissions

Tags: ansible

I am scratching my head to why my code is not registering files in the dict

something wrong with my code in the playbook but cannot see what

```
  vars:
    file_vars:
     - { spath: /var/log/ctm, type: file, mode: o-w, pattern: "^.*?\\.(?:sh|fp|so|xml)$" }

  tasks:
  - name: Find files depending on REGEX pattern
    find:
     paths: "{{ item.spath }}"
     file_type: "{{ item.type }}"
     recurse: yes
     patterns: "{{ item.pattern }}"
     use_regex: yes
    with_items:
     - "{{ file_vars }}"
    register: change_mode

  - debug:
     var: change_mode

  - name: remove world writable permissions
    file:
     path:  "{{ item.path }}"
     mode:  o-w
    with_items:
     -  "{{ change_mode.files }}"
```

> FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"}

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you clarify what `finf` is (in your title)? Also, you should provide information about your environment, i.e. which ansible and OS version, what specific command you are running, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the output of your task `debug` you'd notice `change_mode` is a dictionary containing `results` list, and not `files`. That's because of the `with_items` loop in your `Find files depending on REGEX pattern` task.

Iterate over `change_mode.results` [with subelements `files`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements):

```
- name: remove world writable permissions
  file:
    path:  "{{ item.1.path }}"
    mode:  o-w
  loop: "{{ change_mode.results | subelements('files') }}"
```

---

<sup>With your current data the loop in `Find files depending on REGEX pattern` task in unnecessary, so you can just remove it, but I assume you want `file_vars` to be extendible.</sup>

Comment: ok that works for me I was refering back to an solution that was not valid for my code and older versions of ansible I guess (still learning!) really appreciate your input cheers

Comment: one thing that I did take note of was that the code loops through all files before making the changes and when I remove the regex I get the following error

ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state

probably to do with memory and because the task will be processing over 7000 files in the direcotory?